# How to escape characters in Haskell's Text.Regex library?

Tags: regex, haskell, escaping, posix-ere

### Introduction

I'm using Haskell's `Text.Regex` library and I want to match some characters that normally have meaning in regular expressions. According to `Text.Regex`'s [documentation](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/regex-compat/0.92/doc/html/Text-Regex.html),

> The syntax of regular expressions is ... that of egrep (i.e.
>   POSIX "extended" regular expressions).

And apparently, escaping in  [POSIX Extended Regular Expressions (ERE)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#POSIX_Extended_Regular_Expressions) uses backslashes [unlike [POSIX Basic Regular Expressions (BRE)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#POSIX_Basic_Regular_Expressions)].

---

### Problem

However, when I try to do something like this:

```
> import Text.Regex
> matchRegex (mkRegex "\*") "*"
```

I get the following error:

```
<interactive>:1:23:
    lexical error in string/character literal at character '*'
```

The same thing happens no matter what character I put after the `\`.

---

### Work-Around

I could do something like this:

```
> matchRegex (mkRegex "[*]") "*"
Just []
```

which works, but it seems like a hack, especially if I want to escape several things in a row (e.g. `mkRegex "[[][(][)][]]"` which matches `[()]`).

---

### Question

Is this the only way to escape in POSIX ERE? Why doesn't Haskell's `Text.Regex` library support `\` escaping like it seems it ought to?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't know the syntax but usually if you want to write back-slash inside a string you need to escape it, meaning:

```
matchRegex (mkRegex "\\*") "*"
```

Does it help?

Answer (score 3):

Try it with two backslashes:

```
matchRegex (mkRegex "\\*") "*"
```

I just tried that with GHCI and it worked.